# Is there a way to set signature format for ECDSA to BER encoding in java?

Tags: java, digital-signature, der, ber

I'm trying to sign a message with a private key. It works well, but the signature is encoded in `DER encoding`. What I want is to get the signature in `BER encoding`. Here is the method used to sign :

```
public static byte[] sign(String plainText, String privateKeyPath) throws 
Exception {
    PrivateKey privateKey = getPrivate(privateKeyPath);
    System.out.println(privateKey.getAlgorithm());
    Signature ecdsaSign = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withECDSA", "BC");
    ecdsaSign.initSign(privateKey);
    ecdsaSign.update(plainText.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    byte[] signature = ecdsaSign.sign();
    return signature;
}
```

I'm using `BouncyCastle library`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DER encoding is valid BER encoding

From X.690 summary in [wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.690)

> DER (Distinguished Encoding Rules) is a restricted variant of BER for producing unequivocal transfer syntax for data structures described by ASN.1. Like CER, DER encodings are valid BER encodings. DER is the same thing as BER with all but one sender's options removed.

Comment: The problem is that, when try to verify BER encoded signature in java, it doesn't work at all.

Comment: DEr is a valid BER, but BER is not a valid DER and probably java requires strict DER. I suggest you post a new question with the code you are using to verify, the details of the error and the origin of the signature.

Comment: Now you juste answer my question. I wanted to know if it was possible to verfiy BER encoded signature in java. You said java probably requires strict DER, that is what I was looking for. I'm able to verify the BER encoded signature with openssl.